# Какой лучший вариант платежной системы для сайта?

Tags: php

**Посоветуйте какие-нибудь платежки**

Comment: Для заказчика лучший, как правило, тот, где меньше комиссия

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

**Все достаточно просто.**

Берешь техническое задание, изучаешь необходимый функционал, расписываешь.

Далее обговариваешь с заказчиком/менеджером какие условия по затратам ему подходят.

Далее локализации, в какой стране будет работать сайт, тоже может быть важно.
Можно взять платежки от действующих топовых банков(Тинькофф, Сбер, Каспи, Альфа и т д), которыми больше всего пользуются в той или иной стране.

Далее изучаем рынок платежных систем в поисковике (Goolge, Yandex, и т д), изучаем, подбираем по финансам  и необходимому функционалу.

**Например:**

> Нужно ли автоматизировать возвраты, смотрим есть ли такой
> функционал у платежной системы. И так далее.

Список некоторых рекомендуемых платежных систем для примера:

1. [CloudPayments](https://cloudpayments.ru/)
2. [PayBox](https://paybox.money/ru/)
3. [Tarlanpayments](https://tarlanpayments.kz/)
4. [Epayment](https://www.epayments.com/ru/)